# Inject object attribute to spring bean

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, config

I want to know how to inject attribute of an Object to another Spring bean in Spring XML configurations? I have declared a bean in configuration file and I want to inject attribute of that bean into another bean.

Update:
Here is the configurations I tried in the spring.xml file.

```
<bean id="cFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean>
        <property name="contactPoints" value="${cassandra.contactpoints}" />
        <property name="port" value="${cassandra.port}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean>
        <property name="cluster" value="${cFactoryBean.object}" />
        <property name="keyspaceName" value="${cassandra.keyspace}" />
        <property name="converter" ref="cConverterBean" />
</bean>
```

I have created cFactoryBean bean and I want to inject object property of cFactoryBean to the 'cluster' property in the sFactoryBean.

Comment: Add what you have tried.

Comment: @Jens I have added a sample code.

Comment: I can not see an `object` property in `cFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

In the following example the attribute connectionManager of the class Dao
refers to the spring bean dbConnectionManager.

```
<bean id="feedbackDao" class="com.foo.Dao" 
    <property name="connectionManager" ref="dbConnectionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="dbConnectionManager" class="com.foo.dao.ConnectionManager" />
```